# ABAddressBook in Swift 2 fails

Tags: swift, contacts, deprecated

In Xcode7/Swift 2, the call

```
ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue()
```

returns a non-null CFArrayRef, but when I cast it "as? NSArray" or "as? [ABRecordRef]" (which used to work) I now get nil. I understand that we should move to the Contacts framework, but the old way should still work for a while. What's up?

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax for Swift 2 requires you to string two casts in a row:

```
let rawCFArrayRef =
  ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)?.takeRetainedValue()

let swiftArray = rawCFArrayRef as? NSArray? as? [ABRecordRef]
```

Note that the ? on NSArray? is crucial.

Comment: Same thing for strings `ABRecordCopyCompositeName(selectedPerson)?.takeRetainedValue() as NSString? as? String`. Irritating! This should have been enforced.